# jquery current element from function parameter

Tags: jquery

i'm using jquery-imagetool plugin for croping images. My jquery code looks like:

```
$('div.image img').imagetool({
    viewportWidth: 171,
    viewportHeight: 267
})
```

I want to get viewportWidth parameter from css of the div.image element so I need to get the current element (img) and call parent() to it.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use each to process the images individually and you can then get the width of the div.

```
$('div.image img').each(function() {
    var width = $(this).closest('div.image').width();
    $(this).imagetool({
        viewportWidth: width,
        viewportHeight: 267
    });
});
```